# DaisyUI Dropdown Exceeding screen

Tags: html, tailwind-css, svelte, daisyui

I am using DaisyUI to implement dropdown menus in my web application. However, on mobile, the dropdown exceeds the bounds of the screen. I've tried a number of solutions. It seems Daisy UI dropdowns are fixed to their parent buttons and can have some alignment options using dropdown-end, dropdown-left, and so on. https://daisyui.com/components/dropdown/

Is there a way to align a dropdown so that it doesn't exceed the view? Or constrict the view so that its elements become a size that is more managable?

Thanks.

[image]

```html
<div class="dy-dropdown">
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-noninteractive-tabindex -->
    <label tabindex="0" class="dy-btn dy-btn-ghost p-0.5 dy-no-animation flex-nowrap">
        <slot name="label" />
    </label>
    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-noninteractive-tabindex -->
    <div
        tabindex="0"
        class="dy-dropdown-content dy-object-left-top dy-menu drop-shadow-lg mt-2.5 z-10"
        class:min-w-[21rem]={cols == 6}
        class:min-w-[17.25rem]={cols == 5}
        style={convertStyle($s['ui.background'])}
        on:blur={() => dispatch('nav-end')}
    >
        <slot name="content" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div className="dropdown dropdown-end">
    ...
</div>
```

I had a similar issue on mobile, where upon clicking the 'search' magnifying glass icon, that my dropdown-content (input search bar) was going directly below the icon, and leading off the page.
By doing dropdown-end, it sends the content to the left side on drop down.